# Convert time of a known timezone to local timezone in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to convert the time ( time alone ) from a known timezone to my local timezone with Moment.js.

I wrote the following function and, I am getting `invalidDate` as the output.

```
const convertToLocalTime = (time, tz) => {

  const t = moment.tz(time, tz)
  const localTime = t.local()
}
```

- `time` is just time; without any date eg: `10:06 am` and,
- `tz` is a timezone string for eg: `Europe/Berlin`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry if I'm just misreading this, but why are you passing two times? It sounds like you want to pass a single `from` time and a time zone and return the the new time in the local zone. What is `to` for?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing two times. That was intentional. the variable names might be misleading - I have two times, from ( like a start time ) and to ( like an end time ) with known tz, and I want to convert them both to local time.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: I think general problem here is that moment works with dates, not times. If you manage to turn time into date and just disregard the date part, this could be a potential solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Parsing in Zone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/):

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Since your input (`10:06 am`) is not in ISO 8601/RFC 2822 recognized format (see [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) docs), you have to pass format parameter as shown in [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a live sample:

```js
const convertToLocalTime = (time, tz) => {
  const t = moment.tz(time, 'hh:mm a', tz)
  const localTime = t.local()
  return localTime;
}

const res = convertToLocalTime("10:06 am", 'Europe/Berlin');
console.log( res.format('hh:mm a') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```